TabView occupies all free space, how to fix it?
I create a TabView, but for some reason it occupies the entire area on the screen although the view it contains is not on the entire screen.
VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedPage) {
                Onboard1()
                    .tag(0)
                Onboard2()
                    .tag(1)
                Onboard3()
                    .tag(2)
                
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .onChange(of: selectedPage) { _ in
                textInBtn = changeTextInBtn()
            }
            GenerateCapsule(selectedPage: $selectedPage, countPage: 3)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)) {
                    selectedPage+=1
                }
            }) {
                Text(textInBtn)
                    .foregroundColor(.text)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.vertical, 17)
                    .background(.block)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13))
            }
            .padding(.horizontal,20)
        }

I tried adding VStack to TabView and generating capsules there but it doesn't look good.

That is just how TabView behaves. Please show the desired result and your current result, as well as a [mcve].

I need the height of TabView to adjust to the height of the content
